# Good Miniature for a Dancing Weapon

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-4e, game-recommendation, miniatures

My DnD Artificer is going to take the Dancing Weapon daily power and I want a miniature to represent the weapon. I've tried doing google searches and looking through the Wizards miniatures and can't find anything. Can anyone suggest a good miniature represent this?

Answer (score 7):

The best solution is probably to make your own. You'll need three things

- The weapon. This can be accomplished one of two ways, steal it from an existing mini, or pick up a weapon sprue from your favorite mini house, look in their conversions section. Don't worry if it has a hand attached to it, you can bury the hand in green stuff.
- Greenstuff. This is a two part epoxy putty that is very common for mini builders and converters. You can buy it at your local craft store or order it online.
- A base. Lots of mini houses sell bases or you can buy a round wooden chip online or at a craft store. Alternatively, you can use a penny/dime/nickle.

Sculpt a bit of the green stuff around the base and mold the mini into it (a dynamic pose should be key here). When the green stuff dries, paint the mini to your specs.

[Robert](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/10979/robert-wolke) linked a nice example of this [here](http://thenecroblogicon.blogspot.ch/2010/05/dungeons-and-dragons-spiritual-weapon.html).

Comment: You could also use a 'flying base' which is a clear plastic base and a short vertical rod. The dreaded Games Workshop used to sell these and I'm sure they are available from other suppliers